# What algorithm is used to implement HermiteH function (mathematica)

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica, hermite

I need to port a numerical simulation written in Wolfram Mathematica to another language. The part that is giving me trouble is that the code is calling the [HermiteH](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html) function with a non-integral order (the parameter `n` is a fractional number, not an integer), which I'm guessing is some extension to Hermite polynomials. What algorithm can be used to implement this function and what does it actually calculate when given a non-integral order?

(I do know how to implement hermite polynomials for integral orders)

Comment: What is the value of `n` in question? If it varies, what is the range of values? Mostly just curious; sometimes algorithms exist for some value or values of parameters and not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=HermiteH

For n different from a non-negative integer, the analytic extension of the Hermite polynomial is given by

[image]

where KummerM is a [Kummer's function (of the first kind) M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) and Γ is a [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)